# SVG Text tag not rendered above group

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, svg

I'm creating a small stacked bar graph, with 3 bar items (rendered with a coloured `<rect>` item). This is all done in a `React` component (I build these up depending on some of the inputs I get). The render function for the component looks something like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <g key={this.props.id}>
    <rect
      width={`${
        this.props.value === 0 ? 2 : this.calculatePercentage(this.props.value)
      }%`}
      height={`15px`}
      x={`${this.getPosition()}%`}
      style={{ fill: this.props.color }}
      className={Styles.bar}
    />
    <text
      y={25}
      x={`${this.getPosition()}%`}
      transform={`translate(${this.getTextPosition()}, 0)`}
    >
      <a
        onClick={this.onClick}
        className={
          this.props.value === 0
            ? Styles.noResults
            : this.props.isSelected
            ? Styles.selectedText
            : Styles.filterText
        }
      >
        {this.props.label}
      </a>
    </text>
  </g>
  <text
    id={"percentage"}
    className={Styles.barText}
    x={`${this.getPosition() + 1}%`}
    y={11}
    transform={`translate(${0}, 0)`}
  >
    {this.calculatePercentage(this.props.value)}%
  </text>
  <use xlinkHref="#percentage" />
</React.Fragment>
```

Ultimately, for a result-set I have, the output from this component looks like this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
    overflow: visible;
}

.barText {
    fill: #000;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.noResults {
    fill: #bcbcbc;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.noResults:hover {
    cursor: default;
}

.selectedText {
    fill: #0078d7;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    text-decoration-color: #0078d7;
    text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.filterText {
    fill: #0078d7;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.filterText:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    text-decoration-color: #0078d7;
    text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="container">   
    <g>
        <rect class="bar" style="fill: #2a7c4f;" x="0%" width="2%" height="15px" />
        <text transform="translate(0)" x="0%" y="25"><a class="noResults">Complete: 0</a></text>
    </g>
    <text id="percentage" class="barText" transform="translate(0)" x="1%" y="11">0%</text>
    <g>
        <rect class="bar" style="fill: #fec42e;" x="2%" width="2%" height="15px" />    
        <text transform="translate(53.91)" x="2%" y="25"><a class="noResults">Draft: 0</a></text>
    </g>
    <text id="percentage" class="barText" transform="translate(0)" x="7%" y="11">48%</text>
    <g>
        <rect class="bar" style="fill: #D3D3D3;" x="4%" width="100%" height="15px" />    
        <text transform="translate(253.91)" x="2%" y="25"><a class="noResults">Empty: 0</a></text>
    </g>
    <text id="percentage" class="barText" transform="translate(0)" x="91%" y="11">50%</text>
  <use xlink:href="#percentage"/>
</svg>
```

Now as you can see, the second `0%` isn't visible, what I want is for all the `%` value fields to be visible on top of the bar itself. Is there any way to go about this? It obviously works if the particular section of the bar has a larger width, but I want it to work regardless of the width of the `rect`.

Comment: move all the text elements at the end of the svg just before the closing tag

Comment: The text elements are added programmatically at the end of each group tag - so that would mean splitting that out into a completely separate component - I was wondering if there's an easier way to not go that route?

Comment: If you look at different graphing solutions (or, incedentally, mapping solutions), you will find that all of them have separate layers for grafical elements and labeling. It's not just a best practice, in SVG there is really no way around it.

Comment: Sigh - it breaks my heart but here we are. Thanks for confirming my darkest suspicions on it - I'll go back to the drawing board on this one.